# Can't change lock screen to a non-password option

Tags: lock-screens, security

This is on a Galaxy Note 3.

1. On Kitkat, in order to access work email we had to install MobileIron, which is a horrible suite of supposedly secure apps. As part of the installation I had to define MobileIron as administrator, and also to encrypt the phone. At that point I used a PIN lock on the lock screen.
2. Recently the Lollipop update became available. To install Lollipop I first had to decrypt the phone. During decryption it asked me to define a high-security password (alphanumeric, not PIN).
3. After decryption it no longer let me change the lock screen back to PIN (all the other options are grayed out, saying that the option was disabled by administrator, encryption policy or credential storage).
4. I tried encrypting it again, it didn't help.
5. I decrypted it back.
6. I removed MobileIron from the administrator list, and then also uninstalled all of the apps in the suite.
7. I installed some more updates following the Lollipop upgrade.
8. I restarted the phone after each step.

Nothing seems to help, all options but the password are still grayed out. What can it be?

Comment: Well, reading this "app"'s reviews in my country tells me that this app changes relevant files, which are not reverted to their initial state upon uninstalling. I won't test this for you, but I fear that only a factory reset might suffice.